# SSIS recordset in script task: cannot use it with subsequent rows

Tags: vb.net, ssis, recordset

I am using a script task in SSIS in which I am using three different recordsets to add rows to the data flow.  Everything works well for the first use of these recordsets, but when additional rows need to access the recordsets, there is no data in them.

What I am trying to do is to take these rows in the incoming data flow:

```
ID |   mScale   |  startDate  | End Date  ....
 1 |    w       |   7/8/13    | 10/31/13
 1 |    m       |   11/1/13   | 3/31/14
 1 |    q       |   4/1/14    | 7/31/14
 2 |    w       |   7/8/13    | 10/31/13
 2 |    m       |   11/1/13   | 3/31/14
 2 |    q       |   4/1/14    | 7/31/14
```

And add rows so the outgoing data flow looks like this:

```
 ID  |  pScale   |   startDate  | EndDate
  1  |    w      |     7/8/13   |  7/14/13
  1  |    w      |     7/15/13  |  7/21/13
  ....
  1  |    w      |    10/28/13  |  10/31/13
  1  |    m      |    11/1/13   |  11/30/13
  1  |    m      |    12/1/13   |  12/31/13
  ...
  1  |    m      |    3/1/14    |  3/31/14
  1  |    q      |    4/1/14    |  6/30/14
  1  |    q      |    7/1/14    |  7/31/14
  2  |    w      |     7/8/13   |  7/14/13
  2  |    w      |     7/15/13  |  7/21/13
  ....
  2  |    w      |    10/28/13  |  10/31/13
  2  |    m      |    11/1/13   |  11/30/13
  2  |    m      |    12/1/13   |  12/31/13
  ...
  2  |    m      |    3/1/14    |  3/31/14
  2  |    q      |    4/1/14    |  6/30/14
  2  |    q      |    7/1/14    |  7/31/14
```

The recordsets contain the weekly, quarterly and monthly start and end dates.

The output rows with the ID of 1 are being created, the output rows with the ID of 2 are not.

I've found information on the internet that says that you can't iterate over the same recordset twice.  I'm wondering if there is a way to regenerate the recordset or reuse it somehow?  Or do I need to rethink this whole design?

Thoughts appreciated, script below.

```
' Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
' Write scripts using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008.
' ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data.OleDb


<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute()> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits UserComponent

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

    Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Difference As TimeSpan

    Try
        If Row.mScale = "w" Then
            'create 17 new rows, pull start date and enddate from the excel sheet.
            oleDA.Fill(dt, Me.ReadOnlyVariables("User::WeeklyData").Value)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                'loop through and find the proper start date,
                j = 0
                For Each dtRow As Data.DataRow In dt.Rows

                    Dim dtStartDate As String = dt.Rows(j)("StartDate").ToString
                    Dim dfStartDate As String = Row.oStartDate.ToString

                    If dfStartDate = dtStartDate Then
                        'start here to populate the next 17 rows.
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next
                For i = 1 To 17
                    With Output0Buffer
                        .AddRow()
                        .PlanID = Row.PlanID
                        .oStartDate = dt.Rows.Item(j)(0).ToString
                        .aFID = Row.aFID
                        .oEndDate = dt.Rows.Item(j)(1).ToString
                        .pScale = Row.mScale
                        .pCount= 1
                        .nwDays = Weekdays(dt.Rows.Item(j)(0), dt.Rows.Item(j)(1))
                        .CreateDate = Today
                        .ModDate = Today
                        j = j + 1
                    End With
                Next
            End If
        End If

        If Row.mScale = "m" Then
            'create 7 new rows, pull start date and enddate from the excel sheet.
            'where to start - the start of the month that is two months out from the project start date?
            'how to add two months to the date?
            oleDA.Fill(dt, Me.ReadOnlyVariables("User::MonthlyData").Value)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                'loop through and find the proper start date,
                j = 0
                For Each dtRow As Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim dtStartDate As String = dt.Rows(j)("StartDate").ToString
                    Dim dfStartDate As String = Row.oStartDate.AddMonths(-2).ToString
                    'Subtract two months from start date.

                    If dfStartDate <= dtStartDate Then
                        'start here to populate the next 7 rows.
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next
                For i = 1 To 7
                    With Output0Buffer
                        .AddRow()
                        .PlanID = Row.PlanID
                        .oStartDate = dt.Rows.Item(j)(0).ToString
                        .aFID = Row.aFID
                        .oEndDate = dt.Rows.Item(j)(1).ToString
                        'need to store this in a variable to use for the start of the quarterly dates.
                        .pScale = Row.mScale
                        .pCount= 1
                        'Calculate .nwDays 
                        'NumWorkDays = dt.Rows.Item(j)(1).Subtract(dt.Rows.Item(j)(0).ToString)
                        '.nwDays = NumWorkDays.TotalDays
                        .nwDays = Weekdays(dt.Rows.Item(j)(0), dt.Rows.Item(j)(1))
                        .CreateDate = Today
                        .ModDate = Today
                        j = j + 1
                    End With
                Next
            End If
        End If

        If Row.mScale = "q" Then
            'create x new rows, pull start date and enddate from the excel sheet.
            oleDA.Fill(dt, Me.ReadOnlyVariables("User::QuarterlyData").Value)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                'loop through and find the proper start date,
                j = 0
                For Each dtRow As Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim dtStartDate As String = dt.Rows(j)("StartDate").ToString

                    If Row.oStartDate <= dtStartDate Then
                        'start here to populate the next x rows until the project end date.
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next

                While dt.Rows.Item(j)(0) <= Row.UpdateAccIDprojEndDate
                    With Output0Buffer
                        .AddRow()
                        .PlanID = Row.PlanID
                        .oStartDate = dt.Rows.Item(j)(0).ToString
                        .aFID = Row.aFID
                        'IF THIS IS WITHIN THE QUARTER WE'RE ON, THEN POPULATE WITH PROJECT END DATE.
                        Difference = dt.Rows.Item(j)(1).Subtract(Row.UpdateAccIDprojEndDate)


                        If (Row.UpdateAccIDprojEndDate < dt.Rows.Item(j)(1)) Then
                            .oEndDate = Row.UpdateAccIDprojEndDate
                            .nwDays = Weekdays(dt.Rows.Item(j)(0), Row.UpdateAccIDprojEndDate)

                        Else
                            .oEndDate = dt.Rows.Item(j)(1).ToString
                            .nwDays = Weekdays(dt.Rows.Item(j)(0), dt.Rows.Item(j)(1))

                        End If
                        .pScale = Row.mScale
                        .pCount= 1
                        .CreateDate = Today
                        .ModDate = Today
                        j = j + 1
                    End With
                End While
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        'use this to do something even if the script task fails.
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function Weekdays(ByRef startDate As Date, ByRef endDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim numWeekdays As Integer
    Dim totalDays As Integer
    Dim WeekendDays As Integer
    numWeekdays = 0
    WeekendDays = 0

    totalDays = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, startDate, endDate) + 1

    For i As Integer = 1 To totalDays

        If DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, startDate) = 1 Then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        End If
        If DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, startDate) = 7 Then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        End If
        startDate = DateAdd("d", 1, startDate)
    Next

    numWeekdays = totalDays - WeekendDays

    Return numWeekdays

End Function


End Class
```

Comment: it's great that you have provided code with your question.  what will make this better though,  is an understanding of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you show the code used to create the recordsets?

Comment: Edited to include more detail on what I'm trying to do.  As far as the recordsets, they are stored in a flat file, and created using an SSIS flat file source which puts the data into a recordset destination (SSIS object variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to create three `DataTable` objects as member variables in your script class - one each for the weekly, monthly and quarterly date lists. Populate them once in the `PreExecute` sub of your script component, and then use them in the `ProcessInputRow` sub:

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Private _monthlyDates As New DataTable
    Private _weeklyDates As New DataTable
    Private _quarterlyDates As New DataTable

    Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
        MyBase.PreExecute()

        Dim monthlyDa As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim weeklyDa As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim quarterlyDa As New OleDbDataAdapter

        monthlyDa.Fill(_monthlyDates, Me.Variables.MonthlyDates)
        weeklyDa.Fill(_weeklyDates, Me.Variables.WeeklyDates)
        quarterlyDa.Fill(_quarterlyDates, Me.Variables.QuarterlyDates);
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        Dim dataTableToCheck As DataTable
        Dim periodStart As Date
        Dim periodEnd As Date
        Dim periodFound As Boolean = False

        ' Choose the appropriate data table based on the mScale value
        Select Case Row.mScale
            Case "w"
                dataTableToCheck = _weeklyDates
            Case "m"
                dataTableToCheck = _monthlyDates
            Case "q"
                dataTableToCheck = _quarterlyDates
            Case Else
                dataTableToCheck = Nothing
        End Select
        ' Do whatever's appropriate with that data
        ' This example populates PeriodStart and PeriodEnd columns
        ' based on the row's StartDate and whether it's a weekly, monthly or quarterly period
        If Not (dataTableToCheck Is Nothing) Then
            For Each dtRow As Data.DataRow In dataTableToCheck.Rows
                periodStart = CDate(dtRow("StartDate"))
                periodEnd = CDate(dtRow("EndDate"))
                If periodStart <= Row.StartDate And Row.StartDate <= periodEnd Then
                    periodFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If periodFound Then
                Row.PeriodStart = periodStart
                Row.PeriodEnd = periodEnd
            Else
                Row.PeriodStart_IsNull = True
                Row.PeriodEnd_IsNull = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The solution you provided above has resolved the original problem.  I'm having a new perplexing issue which I will ask about in a different question.  Thanks for your help.