# SSIS Variables Going Out of Scope

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a file I want to compare against entries I have in the database using a SSIS project.

In my ControlFlow I have 'Execute SQL Task' which fetches me a list of results from the database which I want to compare against in my 'Script Task'. There is other stuff happening here that I don't know about but there is for loops before I reach my 'Script Task'.

It works fine the first time I run it but once it tries the second entry in the file it lost the database results. I was able to fix this by filling the database results in PreExecute()

```cs
private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    //filling results from database into DataTable object
    adapter.Fill(dt, this.Variables.AccountFilterVariables); 

}
```

but now each time it goes into a loop in ControlFlow I am losing the results that are held in this.Variables.AccountFilterVariables

I am able to fix this by putting my 'Execute SQL Task' into the loop but I don't want it to query the database base each time. I just want to query the database once and keep this.Variables.AccountFilterVariables for the lifetime of the project.

How do I do this? I am guessing its something to do with PostExecute() but I am not sure what.

[image: Control FLow]

[image: Data Flow]

Comment: Could you pop a screenshot of the control flow and data flows involved? I think I know what you're doing but a picture would solidify

Comment: It seems I need a higher reputation to upload photos but here is a link to my ControlFlow http://i.stack.imgur.com/HFgf8.jpg DataFlow http://i39.tinypic.com/24zg9r5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the recordset created by the Execute SQL Task is of the [forward-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) cursor type, which means you can only read through it once.

A simple workaround is to add a Script Task immediately following the Execute SQL Task. In that Script Task, load a DataTable with the recordset and store that DataTable in another package-scope variable. Then, within your various loops, your Script Components can reference the DataTable, which by default allows seeking forward and backwards.

For sample code, see my answer to [SSIS recordset in script task: cannot use it with subsequent rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187488/ssis-recordset-in-script-task-cannot-use-it-with-subsequent-rows).